# Unable to solve solidity error- ParserError: Expected ';' but got 'Number' --> first.sol:2:17: | 2 | Pragma solidity 0.8.7; | ^^^

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, nft

I am using solidity programming and getting errors during compilation  ParserError: Expected ';' but got 'Number'  --> first.sol:2:17:   | 2 | Pragma solidity 0.8.7;   |                 ^^^

Comment: show us the code file first.sol.

Answer (score 0):

letter "p" of pragma should be small letter.

Try: pragma solidity 0.8.7;

(instead of: Pragma solidity 0.8.7;)